# Problem while loading Images from Training folder having only one folder

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to run Siamese Network implemented in Pytorch for my custom made data set. 
Github Link for Code : https://github.com/viral-parmar/Voice_Dissimilarity
When I try to run the code and provide the path to Training data having only one folder with 10 images only. The Data Loading part of Code Take lots of execution time and never gets executed successfully. But When I provide the path to same Training Data, now having like 25 Folders Each having 10 Images, the loading part gets executed successfully. I don't understand the problem with code.

I tried it running on Google Co Lab and also on my local computer, but the results are same.

```
folder_dataset = dset.ImageFolder(root=Config.training_dir)

siamese_dataset = SiameseNetworkDataset(imageFolderDataset=folder_dataset,
                                    transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((100,100)),
                                                                  transforms.ToTensor()
                                                                  ])
                                   ,should_invert=False)

#Visualising some of the data
vis_dataloader = DataLoader(siamese_dataset,
                    shuffle=True,
                    num_workers=8,
                    batch_size=8)
dataiter = iter(vis_dataloader)


example_batch = next(dataiter)
concatenated = torch.cat((example_batch[0],example_batch[1]),0)
imshow(torchvision.utils.make_grid(concatenated))
print(example_batch[2].numpy())
```

It takes long and never gets executed completely.

Answer (score 0):

So I think the `num_workers=8` is the part causing the problem. Basically the overhead for distribution is taking much more time. Try changing it to 1 i.e. `num_workers=1` and running again. For 10 images you wouldn't need 8 cores :P

Hope this helps!

Comment: Still the same problem :(.

Comment: its the while loops!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure now that its coz of these while loops. basically check if in those 10 images you have both classes or not? if its the same class for all 10 images the loop will never break.

```
        while True:
            #keep looping till the same class image is found
            img1_tuple = random.choice(self.imageFolderDataset.imgs) 
            if img0_tuple[1]==img1_tuple[1]:
                break
    else:
        while True:
            #keep looping till a different class image is found

            img1_tuple = random.choice(self.imageFolderDataset.imgs) 
            if img0_tuple[1] !=img1_tuple[1]:
                break
```

Comment: All the 10 images are of same class only. So if that's the problem then keeping images / folder of two class will not create this problem I guess ?

Comment: yup the comment says it all - ` #keep looping till a different class image is found`